# Angular Universal - Deploying to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, express, angular-universal

I have been trying and failing for over three days now to get this working, and am growing increasingly frustrated with my own lack of understanding on the topic - so this is my search for an answer that I've not yet found.

I am using Angular 9.x and Angular Universal 9.x and am unable to work out how to deploy this to Elastic Beanstalk on a server running node. There are zero tutorials that explain how this should be done, as they are all aimed at those wanting to use Lambda on AWS. If someone could please point me in the right direction that would be great. I run npm run build:ssr --prod, and get the following in my dist folder:

[[image: Dist folder[1]]

I have tried deploying this folder by uploading it zipped, as well as tried `eb deploy` with my whole app - but all of these result in errors like the following (for eb deploy method)

```
> blush-front-end@0.0.0 start /var/app/current
> ng serve

sh: ng: command not found
```

Could someone please point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Do you have `.extenstions` folder were you can specify dependencies to be installed?

Comment: No I don't have one of those - is that the following you're referring to? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

Comment: Yes. You can specify [packages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages) which are required by your project to be installed on EB instances.

Comment: I am aware, however I understood my node-modules to have everything I need in it, as angular CLI is in my package.json

Comment: So what additional packages would I be needing here?

Comment: `ng: command not found` the ng is missing somewhere. Don't know how you have it all setup.

Comment: I don't know Elastic beanstalk, but what you want in the end is to run the `server/main.js` script with nodejs. So you need to install nodejs on your server, using the packages. You do not need the CLI after that, or the node_modules folder fro your project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I struggled for months too because of the lack of tutorials online on how to deploy Angular Universal to AWS Elastic Beanstalk. And you will now be very happy to know how easy it is.

First, run the command `npm run build:ssr` to build for production.

Inside the dist folder, you will probably find a folder with your project name. Inside this folder you will find a "browser" folder and a "server" folder. Inside the "server" folder it is the main.js file.

Your setup might be slightly different, but you will be able to adjust this explanation to your situation after you read my entire answer.

**Zip the dist folder.**

Let's now configure the environment in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

1) When you create an environment in Elastic Beanstalk, choose "Web server environment", and then on Platform branch config, choose the last option: "Node.js running on 64bit Amazon Linux". This is a very important step, since this is the only option that will enable you to configure the Container Options.

2) On the Application code, choose "Upload your code" and upload your zip file.

3) Click on Configure more options

4) Click on the Edit button on the Software box.

5) On the Node command field,type `node dist/yourProjectFolderName/server/main.js`

That's it!! Save and create your environment. Your app will work now. :-)

Comment: If I could kiss you, I would. Thank you so much!

Comment: 504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.16.1 ¿Any ideas?

Comment: Now you add a `Procfile` to the files that get deployed to the EB server, the contents should be the same as the Node command field mentioned above but prefixed with `web:` so `web: node dist/yourProjectFolderName/server/main.js`